# echo array of images using codeigniter and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have had GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL database, so I have created view where is a row of an array of images. here it is:

[image: in hotel_images column I have array of images]

I am using PHP CodeIgniter and I try to display this images on my page, but there is some problem: it shows only those images, which are not in an array in the table row. 
here is my code to display:

```
<?php foreach ($get_hotels as $geth) { ?>

<td><img src="<?php echo base_url()."uploads/hotels/".trim(str_replace(",", " ", $geth->hotel_images));?>" width="73" height="53"></td>

<?php } ?>
```

So, my question is how to display pictures in same `<td>` as an array? any suggestions?

Comment: addition my link in inspect element looks like this: <img src="http://localhost/rafo/uploads/hotels/3175.jpg  157707-OVFLQZ-651.jpg" width="73" height="53">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following method:

```
<?php

foreach($get_hotels as $geth):
    $images = explode(',', $geth->hotel_images);
    foreach($images as $image): ?>
<td>
    <img src="<?= base_url() . "uploads/hotels/$image"; ?>" width="73" height="53">
</td>
    <?php
    endforeach; ?>

<?php
endforeach; ?>
```

This uses explode to separate the values by comma and then, runs a loop over them and prints the image tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with explode, like this :

```
$images = explode(',',$your query);
<?php foreach ($images as $key => $geth) { ?>

<td><img src="<?php echo base_url()."uploads/hotels/".$geth;?>" width="73" height="53"></td>

<?php } ?>
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: Nothing happen, i just give an example for your problem, If you know what is my point, you can solve your problem